# How to create a 3d plot using two separate datasets? in R

Tags: r, plot3d, scatterplot3d

I have two separate datasets that I would like to plot in both a scatterplot3d and a plot3d in r
How can I do that? I can make the two plots for the datasets individually with just the following:

```
H <-as.numeric(Dataset$Height)

D <- Dataset$Dose

W <- Dataset$Weight

scatterplot3d(x= W,y= H, z = D, 
              main="Title")
plot3d(x= W,y= H, z = D, col="red", size=7 )
```

How can I combine the two datasets into one scatterplot3d and one plot3d? The new plots would have the same axises as the ones above.
I have attached a picture to hopefully help understand the structure of the datasets

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIx2E.png)

the dput looks like this:

Comment: could you provide `dput(Dataset)` and the other dataset? Combining two datasets could be as simple as `rbind(Dataset1,Dataset2)`

Comment: Thanks for the `dput` but it would be easier to get a copy as text instead of an image so that it can be processed.

Comment: I tried to include a copy paste of the dput, but it is too long. Would it be possible to color the datapoint for the two dataset while using rbind? and thank you for your reply

Comment: you could use  `dput(head(dataset,10))`. If I understand you well, you'd like to have a different color for each dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a `color` column to each dataset and `rbind`them :

```
library(scatterplot3d)


m1 <- head(mtcars,10)
m1$color <- 1

m2 <- tail(mtcars,10)
m2$color <- 2 

m <- rbind(m1,m2)

W <- m$cyl
H <- m$mpg
D <- m$disp
C <- m$color

scatterplot3d(x = W, y = H, z = D, 
              main = "Title", color = C)
```

[image]

Comment: @ Waldi. Do you know where the second dataset is. I think we have 3 columns and 3 rows?!

Comment: Should the color column in each dataset just have two different colors like red and green al the way through?

Comment: @Waldi I just read your comment about adding the color columns that explains why it didn't work for me

Comment: Yes exactly, each one should have a different factor level

Comment: @TarJae, as we had troubles with `dput` of the original dataset, I went for `mtcars`

Comment: @Waldi I gave each dataset a color column as a factor w 1 level but I get this message:  length(color) must be equal length(x) or 1

Comment: did you simply try what I did in my example : `dataset1$color <- 1` and `dataset2$color<-2`, then `rbind`. this should work.

Comment: @Waldi Thank you so much for your help and patience with me. The error was caused by me writing color with an uppercase C. It is working perfectly now :-) Would the same work for plot3d?

Comment: @Waldi I am getting this message: formal argument "color" matched by multiple actual arguments

Comment: which package are you using for `plot3d`?

Comment: I am using plot3D

Comment: The color argument is called `col`. This works for me : `plot3d(x= W,y= H, z = D, main="Title",col=C)`